# A rigorous proof of $\Re\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\log\left(\frac{1}{1-ne^{i\theta}}\right)\right)d\theta=2\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, mobius-function

We denote the real part of a complex number $z$, as $\Re z$, then I was thinking an exercise. Just I've combined a formula from a course notes and did some manipulations, now I would like to know if we can prove it rigorously. Thus I don't know if there is some special issue about convergence that we need to justify.

For integers $n\geq 1$, wedenote the Möbius function as $\mu(n)$; see the definition of this arithmetic function from this [MathWorld.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html)

> **Question.** Prove justifying rigorously each step that (I presume that my identity is right) $$\Re\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\log\left(\frac{1}{1-ne^{i\theta}}\right)\right)d\theta=2\pi.\tag{1}$$
>   **Thanks you in advance.**

Thus I omit my symbolic manipulations and combinations, waiting for your rigorous proof.

*Sketch of my calculations.* First I've take the specialization $n\geq 1$ of a formula in [1], page 55, a formlula related to the Poisson kernel, and from this I wrote $$\Re\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\log\left(1-ne^{i\theta}\right)\right)d\theta=2\pi\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\log n,$$ after I've combined with the formula $(11)$ of previous MathWorld's article that I've cited. As I've said I don't know if there is some issue of convergence and how justify it rigorousliy.$\square$

**Added as atempt of proof:**

From $$\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\log\left(\frac{1}{1-ne^{i\theta}}\right)\right)d\theta=-\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\left(\log n\log+\left(\frac{1}{n}-e^{i\theta}\right)\right)\right)d\theta,$$
I can to write $$2\pi-\Re\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\log\left(\frac{1}{n}-e^{i\theta}\right)\right)d\theta=2\pi.$$

### References:

[1] Jack D’Aurizio, Superior Mathematics from an Elementary point of view, course notes, University of Pisa (2017-2018).

Comment: Perhaps your symbolic manipulations aren't that far from a proof, it can only be helpful if you post  (an outline of) them.

Comment: Yes, @barto many thanks now I add a sketch.

Comment: @barto That would be interesting, indeed.

Comment: While it is true that $\int_0^{2\pi} \log(1- ne^{i\theta}) = 2\pi \log n$, I do not see how the Möbius function enters the game?

Comment: My calculation was symbolic @Fabian , there is a typo in my second formula, I've combined with $(11)$ of MathWorld's article. Many thanks.

Comment: Now I agree. There is only one step where you calculation is "symbolic" and that is when you interchange the sum and the integral (so you should think about justifying this step). By the way the real part is not needed as the result is real anyway.

Comment: The main question here is whether you can "interchange" the integral and the sum.

Comment: Yes @i707107 many thanks.

Comment: Everyone I think that I need to invoke a thorem like dominated convergence theorem.